# run .exe in the background

Tags: windows-xp

I know that if you want to run a program in the background from a unix command line, you simply add & to the end of the command, but is there an equivalent in windows in order to run something in the background?

Answer (score 4):

A low-budget way of doing this is:

```
start /min some.exe
```

This starts the program in a minimised console window, and doesn't wait for the second program to finish.

Comment: Does what it says. But it would be great if it didn't open a window altogether

Comment: @PrajwalDhatwalia: In that case, use `start /b some.exe` which will run the new process in the background. If the new process makes any console output, it will go to the existing window that you ran `start` from.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. By using the option /b, the bat script does not open a new window to run some.exe. However, bat script itself runs in a window which is still visible. FYI, I launch the bat script by double-clicking on the bat script's icon (GUI).

Answer (score 3):

You can:

1. Use Windows Scheduler.
2. Run the exe as a Windows service.

I don't really know of a way to manually start something and have it run in the background like you can do in Unix.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a definitive answer to your question there was a similar question on serverfault here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/121979/tools-to-run-a-background-process-command-line-in-windows

The closest thing in windows to the Linux & is described here from what I can tell:

http://blog.commandlinekungfu.com/2009/04/episode-23-job-control.html